# Resolve JPA association while deserializing JAX-RS JSON Object

Tags: java, json, jpa, jackson, jax-rs

I have some problems combining JAX-RS (in JBoss Wildfly container) with JSON payload and with JPA assiciations. Follwoing scenario:

There are two JPA entities

```
@Entity
class Organization {
  @Id
  private long id;

  private String name;
}

@Entity
class Empolyee {
  @Id
  private long id;

  @Id
  private String name;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JsonProperty("organization_id")
  @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
  @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
  private Organization organization;
}
```

Next I have a JAX-RS service to create a new Employee with the following signature:

```
@POST
@Consumes({ "application/json" })
public Response create(final Employee employee) {
}
```

The JSON for a new Employee sent by the client looks like:

```
{
  "name" : "Sam Sample",
  "organization_id" : 2
}
```

My problem is that this JSON (obviously) cannot be deserialized into an instance of "Employee" since the mapping of the "organization_id" to the corresponding JPA Entity fails.

How can I configure JAX-RS (or the Jackson JSON mapper) to interpret the "orgainization_id" as the id of a JPA entity?

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem?

Comment: We have worked around this problem by introducing DTO objects to which the JSON payload is converted first before merging it into our Unit-Of-Work. Not really smart but it works ...

Comment: @woelfle How exactly were you able to register the object mapper such that you could inject in the EntityManager? I wish to write a similar custom deserializer to deserialize the exact class that is being passed in as the POST body of a request. I need to be able to inject the EntityManager using Jersey's HK2, because that is how I have set it up. I just need the ObjectMapper to be managed by Jersey somehow.

Comment: @vikarjramun as mentioned in my last comment we are not injecting the EntityManager in a deserializer at all. What we are doing is deserializing the JSON payload into dedicated DTO objects. In the sample case this would mean to have a DTO with the following structure: 

class EmployeeDTO { 
    private String name, 
    long organizationId 
}

Now we are deserializing the JSON payload into instances of this DTO. I.e. the signature of the JAX-RS endpoint now uses the EmployeeDTO.

This DTO is being converted into an Employee object in the JAX-RS endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

With Jackson you could define a custom deserializer (see [this](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization) and [this](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomDeserializers)) that fetches the `Organization` entity based on the value of `organization_id`.

**Edit**:
Check this example for how to configure JAX-RS using Jackson with a custom deserializer programmatically (as opposed to via annotations):

```
@Provider
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class JacksonContextResolver implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public JacksonContextResolver() throws Exception {
        this.objectMapper = new ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        SimpleModule myModule = new SimpleModule("MyModule", new Version(1, 0, 0, null));
        myModule.addDeserializer(MyType.class, new MyTypeDeserializer());
        objectMapper.registerModule(myModule);

    }

     public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> objectType) {
         return objectMapper;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've already tried writing my own Jackson Deserializer but i have not found any documentation on how to inject the current EntityManager instance into the Deserializer

Comment: How are you registering the custom deserializer? If you are using dependency injection I think you should be able to inject the EntityManager using the `@PersistenceContext` annotation.

Comment: I've registered the deserializer using the @JsonDeserialize annotation. Is there another way to register it?

Comment: Thanks again for the help. I've tried registering the deserializer using a context resolver. Seems that that deserializer is used only when deserializing 'Organization' objects (when calling the JAX-RS service to create an Organization) but it is not used when deserializing the reference to an Organization while creating an Employee.